# Show tag wiki tooltip for jobs tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

Say I see a job that is tagged [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo), and it looks cool enough that I am now curious about [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo).  Right now, hovering on the tag doesn't tell me anything, and clicking on the tag just sends me to a filtered list of jobs that are tagged [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo).

In order to learn more about it, I have to navigate my own way to stackoverflow.com/tags/foo/info, or google "foo", or whatever.

Since the hovering action currently doesn't do anything, could we make it show the tag wiki tooltip?

This would be helpful for people who aren't job hunting but just curious about what skills are in demand.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. We'll review it.